Equivalent brushed DC motor for replacing a PMSM motor
I am trying to understand the relationship between voltage and speed on PMSM vs brushed DC motors.
Assuming efficiency is 100% in both motors and there are no losses, and keeping the same load for both motors, what is the equivalent rated voltage required for the DC motor to replace a 240 VAC 50Hz single-phase PMSM motor to achieve the same speed?

The question is ill-founded. Synchronous motors run at a fixed speed depending on the number of poles they have, while the speed of a DC motor depends on the load. Without knowing the load and the number of poles of the synchronous motor, it's impossible to spec an equivalent DC motor. And then the required specs would be more than just the voltage, because you can make DC motors that run at all sorts of different speeds for the same input voltage and load, just by changing the windings.

Let's say we have 2 pole pmsm motor running at 3000rpm at 240V 50Hz input direct online supply.
We keep the windings, the same as that of the windings on the pmsm stator, on the dc motor rotor with 2 splits on the commutator ring.
Essentially I am trying to understand, when all are equal (or equivalent) what is the voltage equivalency to maintain the same max speed on the dc motor.

You left out what the load on the motor is. We need to know that in order to answer.

Are you thinking of a shunt dc motor? Do you need the load if we use a dc motor with permanent magnet stator?

A permanent-magnet DC motor is pretty much exactly equivalent to a shunt-wound DC motor, except in that the stator draws no current.

I am confused because, my understanding is that a single phase 2-pole PMSM motor connected to Square wave (at rated frequency of motor) with rms 240 VAC voltage would be equivalent to 2 splits in ring DC motor with 2 pole permanent magnet stator and terminals connected to 240*sqrt(2)=340 VDC irrespective of the load. If my understanding is flawed, where am I going wrong? Otherwise, would the current consumption be the same in both motors for the same load?
